# How do I fix CORS issues in Cloudfront CDN?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn, cors

I run a WordPress website and recently configured a CDN using CloudFront.

Most of the features are working fine, but I'm experiencing CORS issues with JS files I'm loading from Github.

I have tried many methods to resolve this issue, but I still get the following error.

```
Ensure CORS response header values are valid

A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request .

To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.

Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible (opaque).
```

This is my setting on Cloudfront -> https://imgsh.net/a/5GFcr4m.jpg

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
GET
HEAD
PUT
POST
PATCH
DELETE
OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
*
Access-Control-Max-Age (seconds)
```

Can someone please advise me on how to resolve this issue?